# printing on a network

Tags: printing

I am having problem printing to any printer at my workplace.  The office use Windows all around.  Even as I see the printers listed in my network settings, I cannot address them to do anything.  The time indicator just spins and spins with no result.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba and look at the install steps. It may be a link, if so follow it. Install Samba for your computer. If you already have Samba, troubleshoot it on the Troubleshoot link.